# Efficient way to implement a bit-wise counter that becomes 1 every (k*n)+i times

Tags: counting, bit-manipulation, optimal-strategy

My question is about [LeetCode "137.Single Number II"](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150):

> **137.Single Number II**
>
> Given an integer array nums where every element appears three times
> except for one, which appears exactly once. Find the single element
> and return it.
>
> You must implement a solution with a linear runtime complexity and use
> only constant extra space.

Is there a generalized way to solve this and similar questions with the minimum number of bit-wise operations? By similar questions, I mean finding a number that appears k' times where other numbers appear k times.

More detail:

To solve this, I implemented a counter such that bit *i* of the counter becomes 1 only when 1 appears 3k+1 times in bit *i* of nums. To do so, I used two integers, A and B, to keep the 1 bit count for each bit *i*. I wrote down a possible sequence for bits in A and B so I could use A as the counter (there were possible other sequences): A<sub>i</sub>B<sub>i</sub> = 00 -> 10 -> 01 -> 00 -> ....
Then, I used a similar approach as calculating a Logic Gate to find bit operations that resulted in the above sequence:

[image: Logic Gate calculation for bit operations that give the above sequence for A and B]

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        A = 0 
        B = 0 
        for num in nums:
            A, B = ((~(A|B))&num)|(A&~num),(A&num)|(B&~num)
        return A
```

With the same approach, I can find any number that repeats k times if all other numbers repeat k' times.

Then I saw this solution:

```
class Solution:
  def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    ones = 0
    twos = 0

    for num in nums:
      ones ^= (num & ~twos)
      twos ^= (num & ~ones)

    return ones
```

This is more efficient and beautiful than mine because it does 6 bitwise operations per num; mine does 10.
What is the most efficient way to implement such counter? How could I know mine was not efficient?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find the exact optimal sequence of instructions to accomplish some effect. I don't know of any systematic way, other than techniques like [superoptimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization), which essentially do a brute-force search over all possibilities.